# how to get GMSMarker X and y coordinate iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

```
CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
```

point wrong values

Printing description of point: `(CGPoint) point = (x=3111.020020, y=-1354.228271)`please help me

Comment: What's `marker.position` values? What values are your expecting?

Comment: marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.f, 35.f);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set `GMSMarker` to all marker set to call method in delay after 1 or 2

```
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(Setviewmarker:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];


  CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
```

`point.x` and `point.y` is position write.......